# What are the correct libraries to connect a SignalR client written in C# with a SignalR server written in C# that uses Azure SignalR?

Tags: c#, azure, signalr

I created a .Net Core 2.1 web service (named SignalRService) that contains a SignalR server.  I posted this service to Azure as a web app.

The code for this service is based on the Microsoft ChatRoom example.

SignalRService contains NuGet references to

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0
Microsoft.Azure.SignalR 1.0.0-preview1-10011
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0
```

The SignalR client is a .Net Framework C# WinForms app that uses a SignalR client class called SignalRClient.

SignalRClient contains NuGet references to

Microsoft.ASpNet.SignalR.Client 2.2.3

When I run the code, I get an error

You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.4, server version null.

I looked at the ChatRoom sample code, but it uses JavaScript for the SignalR client code.

Which versions of which Microsoft packages do I need to use to get this code working?

Comment: You are using the SignalR client for a SignalR Core server. Use the SignalR Core client library instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client

Comment: My web service (SignalRService) is a .Net Core 2.1 app, because it is based on the Microsoft sample web site ChatRoom.  My client application is a WinForms app (MyApp) that uses .Net Framework 4.6.1.  MyApp uses a class library I wrote (SignalRClient) to send and receive SignalR messages.  SignalRClient is a .Net Framework 4.5 class library.  Unless I misunderstand, to use the library you mentioned I would have to create a .Net core version of SignalRClient, which I couldn't use in my .Net Framework WinForms app.  Is this correct?

Comment: No, from where did you get that idea? The SignalR Core client library targets .NET Standard 2.0 not .NET Core 2.0. .NET Standard 2.0 is compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.1 and above though, so you will have to update that outdated 4.5

Comment: Sounds good. I found SignalR Core client library and created a .Net Standard class to act as my SignalR client class. I tried to use the code from my previous client class (new HubConnection(), myHubConnection.CreateHubProxy("hubname") etc, but this library seems to have a very different API. Is there some sample C# (not JS) code showing how to make SignalR client calls using this library?

Comment: Sure, Microsoft even hosts an entire GitHub repo for samples: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples